# Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate works in .NET Core, but not in .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am testing an SDK written in C#, that came with a demo console application written in .NET Core 2.0. I am trying to make a copy of that application in WPF and leave code the same as much as possible. I get this exception in a method call to the SDK API that adds certain callbacks: *Cannot marshal 'parameter #3': Generic types cannot be marshaled.* This is from a call to Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate inside their method. I didn't change any of the code, and it is working in their demo app and throwing an exception in mine. Here is the method call:

```
_tracking_callback_id =
            video_worker.addTrackingCallback(
                TrackingCallback,
                this);
```

and here is the callback itself as defined in their API:

```
public delegate void TrackingCallback(int stream_id, int frame_id, List<RawSample> samples, List<bool> samples_weak, List<float> samples_quality, object userdata);
```

This also happens when I make a .NET Framework console application copy of their demo, so that indicates it has something to do with .NET Core, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Put the delegate a copy of the delegate you are using in a static variable (or in a variable that has the same lifetime as the `video_worker`), otherwise the GC will free the delegate.

Comment: Creating a `List<T>` from unmanaged data considerably boggles my mind.  It is not T that is the problem, but where the heck is it getting the collection size from?  CoreCLR does its own thing, *might* have something to do with a WinRT type projection.  But it certainly is not possible in the desktop CLR version.  All you can do is contact the SDK provider and give them the "hey, this can't work in a WPF".  Do ask about collection size too, it is way too smelly.

Comment: @HansPassant I reported the issue to the SDK provider and they admitted it was a bug in their code and that they would with fix it for the next SDK version.